# why does linkedin REST api group discussion post does not return full response?

Tags: rest, post, response, linkedin-api

I am posting to LinkedIn group discussion endpoint

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/{group-id}/posts
```

and am getting different response from different servers.

Once from the production server, the response I get back contains only PART of the response

in JSON format

```
{
"url":"http:\\api.linkedin.com\v1\groups\{group-id}\posts",
"http_code":201,
"download_content_length":0,
"size_download":0,
"size_upload":363
}
```

once from the development server, the response i get back contains the FULL response

in JSON format

```
{
"http_code":201,
"url":"http:\\api.linkedin.com\v1\groups\{group-id}\posts",
"header_size":536,
"request_size":871,
"filetime":-1,
"ssl_verify_result":0,
"redirect_count":0,
"total_time":1.513264,
"namelookup_time":0.213188,
"connect_time":0.449284,
"pretransfer_time":0.449346,
"size_upload":421,
"size_download":0,
"speed_download":0,
"speed_upload":278,
"download_content_length":0,
"upload_content_length":421,
"starttransfer_time":1.51323,
"redirect_time":0,
"headers_recv":"HTTP/1.1 201 Created Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 x-li-request-id: PJRKH2SBF1 Location: http://\\api.linkedin.com\v1\posts\{post-id} X-LI-R2-W-IC-2: frm.scp=%7B%22refTime%22%3A1372946874%2C%22A.5070905%22%3A360%7D X-LI-R2-W-IC-2: com.linkedin.container.drc=1%7EAPRG%2C1 X-LI-R2-W-IC-2: com.linkedin.container.rpc.cluster.serviceInfo=PROD-ELA4%2Fappreg%2F0.0.2000-RC1.20722%2Fela4-app0213%2Fi001 X-LI-R2-W-IC-2: com.linkedin.container.dsc=1 Content-Length: 0 Vary: Accept-Encoding Date: Thu, 04 Jul 2013 14:07:53 GMT "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which information LinkedIn should return for the request.

https:\api.linkedin.com\v1\groups{group-id}/posts:(creation-timestamp,title,summary,site-group-post-url,creator:(first-name,last-name,picture-url,headline),likes,attachment:(image-url,content-domain,content-url,title,summary),comments:(creator:(first-name,last-name,picture-url),creation-timestamp,text),relation-to-viewer)

Don't forget to use https instead of http.